# Hide rows in table B which already appear in table A

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using this code :

```
    var table1 = $('#TableA').find('td:eq(1)').text();

    var table2 = $("#TableB tr:gt(0)");

    table2.each(function (i) {
        var tds = $(this).children('td');
        var type= +tds.eq(0).text();
        var price = +tds.eq(1).text();
        if (price == table1) {
            var myTable = table2.filter(function () {
                var tds = $(this).children('td');

            })
            myTable.add(this).hide()
        }
    })
```

My Html Page Structure

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="TableA">
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Ref No</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mouse</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>#101255</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Speaker</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>#21165</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="TableB">
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Ref No</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mouse</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>#101255</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Speaker</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>#21165</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Keyboard</td>
            <td>150</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>#31234</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

*"The second table in the images is the Table B"*

My Table B changes from this :
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Zft.png)

To this : [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F3sQ.png)

Now my problem is, only one row is hidden. The row, where "speaker" is, is still displayed. I know that I must use a loop for this, but I don't where to implement the loop and how. I'm a newbie programmer and I know that I need more practice. Please Help Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').click(function(e){

        var table1_tr = $('#TableA').find('tr'); <!--get the rows of first table-->
        var table2 = $("#TableB tr:gt(0)");

        table1_tr.each(function(i,e){ <!-- loop through rows of first table -->
            var table1 = $(e).find('td:eq(1)').text();
            table2.each(function (i) {
                var tds = $(this).children('td');
                var type= +tds.eq(0).text();
                var price = +tds.eq(1).text();
                if (price == table1) {
                    var myTable = table2.filter(function () {
                        var tds = $(this).children('td');

                    })
                    myTable.add(this).hide()
                }
            });
        })
    });

</script>
```

you are checking the text of `price` in the first row of first table with `td` text of all the rows of second table

I modified script to loop through rows of first table and check them with all rows of second table
Hope this helps

Comment: Oh. I get it!  Thank you very much sir